# Can't remove space from value in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

These are the values in my DataFrame

[image]

What I am trying to do, is to change the datatype of columns from string to float, but I can't because some of the values in `df` are written with the space.

What I've already tried:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.strip()
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace(' ','')
```

Nothing helps... Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: could you please add the data of `print(df['Value'])` to your question (you shouldn't post data as image). Your 2nd approach with `str.replace` should actually work.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Is your columns really of datatype `str` or is this just the visualisation of your IDE?

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(str).str.replace(' ','').astype(float)
```

If it does not, try to troubleshoot with the following:

```
def check_cell(x):
    try:
        x = float(str(x).replace(' ', ''))
        return x
    except:
        print(x)
        
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: check_cell(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this variant:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace(' ', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Convert string to float: `df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype('float')`

Comment: `' '` isn't a regular expression. why explicitly add the overhead of `regex=True`?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Pandas is giving a warning in some versions if you don't specify `regex=True/False` so they possibly just don't understand what it means. I agree that it'd be better as `regex=False` here.

Comment: sure, though it's a FutureWarning - that's just an indication that the default behavior is going to change. @Robert Haas if you want to suppress any warnings you might be getting, you can use `regex=False` to explicitly indicate that you *don't* want to use regex.

Answer (score -1):

As the OP says, they want the result to be a Series of `float`, not `str`. A safe way to do this is, after removing any potential spaces, to use [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```py
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'].str.replace(' ', '', regex=False))
```